# How to implement scroll view moved by tableview?

Tags: ios, user-interface

When I move collectionView(foods with picture and price) up or down, the buttons (or tableviews, categories of food)in the red rect will scroll to the corresponding position. Anybody could kindly give some keywords or link that have sample example?
[image]

Comment: could not get your question. If you are trying to add any view on section then I would suggest add header view in your collectionview. In headerview you can do customisation as per your need.

Comment: Guessing you implemented scrollViewDidScroll in your view controller but did not check which scrollview.

Comment: I mean, if I move the collection view(foods with picture and price), on the top in the red rectangle, the buttons will move with the collection view to the corresponding position, how to implement this?

Comment: is your question is : if you scroll the foods then respective food category (main dishes, sides, deserts) will get scroll to centre and get highlighted. right ?